# Data Fusion Driver Issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am having an issue getting a pipeline up and running. I am trying to move data from a CloudSQL MySQL instance to Big Query. In the pipeline I have tried using the MySQL, CloudSQL MySQL and Database sources, but I get the same error each time:

Database Source:

Spark program 'phase-1' failed with error: Plugin with id Database:source.jdbc.mysql does not exist in program phase-1 of ap

plication gs_test_two.. Please check the system logs for more details.

MySQL Source:

Spark program 'phase-1' failed with error: Plugin with id MySQL2:source.jdbc.mysql does not exist in program phase-1 of application gs_test_two.. Please check the system logs for more details.

CloudSQLMySQL Source:

Spark program 'phase-1' failed with error: Plugin with id CloudSQL MySQL:source.jdbc.cloudsql-mysql does not exist in program phase-1 of application gs_test_two.. Please check the system logs for more details.

So as you can see, basically the same error each time.

I know the connections work, as I can look up the MySQL Databases and see table schemas and data through them. What could I be doing wrong here? It's like the pipeline isn't talking to the connections properly.

The instance is on a dedicated VPC with private IP, we have a VM running cloudSQL proxy, private IP is enabled on the database and is peered to the same VPC.

I also tried to run the pipeline, expecting data to be copied from CloudSQL MySQL DB to Big Query, but getting the above errors.